# Red5: Error: Could not find or load main class org.red5.server.Bootstrap

Tags: red5

I am doing a red5 eclipse integration using the following directions:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GncMDOEeUSyWxm6OM1Cedtl6BeJ2ppU-J-TIIKODreo/edit#heading=h.crcr7jpvtmhj

Versions: java8
Red5: 1.0.2-RC4

When I am starting the red5-server as java application debug, it is working fine

But on starting the server in the last step I am getting the following error

Running on  Linux
Starting Red5
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option UseStringCache; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using the ParNew young collector with the Serial old collector is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
Error: Could not find or load main class org.red5.server.Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Build and / or use the tarball or zip file; extract the jars and you'll have a server jar and another jar containing the bootstrap class. For version 1.0.2 I believe it will be named red5-bootstrap.jar; the sh and bat files will contain the correct jar file paths.